# k-means clustering implementation in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cluster-analysis, k-means

**I'm in need for a Javascript implementation of the k-means clustering algorithm.** I only have 1-dimensional data and rarely more than 100 items, so performance is not an issue.

PS: I could only find [one](http://code.google.com/p/figue/) but it seems extremely unsteady, resulting in completely different clusters on virtually every call.

Comment: You can try to implement it yourself. If you can't find any implementation, try to do it cos it is not hard to implement.

Comment: Did you check here: http://code.google.com/p/bioblitz/source/browse/trunk/ftadmin/public/javascripts/visualization/kmeans.js?r=77

Answer (score 9, accepted):

k-means in Javascript:

http://code.google.com/p/hdict/source/browse/gae/files/kmeans.js

http://www.mymessedupmind.co.uk/index.php/javascript-k-mean-algorithm

Applet:

http://www.math.le.ac.uk/people/ag153/homepage/KmeansKmedoids/kmeans.jar

Comment: The first one is 2D only, the second one doesn't work ("error: newgroup is not defined"), 3rd is java not javascript

Comment: @johnktejik did you find an alternative?

Answer (score 6):

In node and the browser:

https://github.com/harthur/clusterfck

You have a choice between **k-means** or **hierarchical clustering** with these distance functions:

1. euclidean
2. manhattan
3. max

Answer (score 0):

Simple K-Means implementation:
[dimas-kmeans](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dimas-kmeans)

```
var kmeans = require('dimas-kmeans')

var clusters = kmeans.getClusters(data);
```